# Getting text from a checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a collection of checkboxes within a bunch of  elements:

```
<label class="control-label">Items</label>
<div class="controls">
    <div id="13" class="checkboxes columns-container columns-count-two">
        <div class="column-item">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="13[]" value="Item 1" type="checkbox">Item 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-item">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="13[]" value="Item 2" type="checkbox">Item 2
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-item">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="13[]" value="Item 3" type="checkbox">Item 3
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following JavaScript code to try and get the text of the checked item, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure what I'm missing, some assistance will be greatly appreciated

```
var checktext = $('#13 input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
return $(this).next("label").text().split(' ').join('%20');
}).get();
```

Comment: Replace `.next("label")` with `.parent()`. This is not [how `.next()` works](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: `next()` gets the next *sibling*.  You want the parent of the `input` element.

Comment: Any reason to not just get the `value` of the checkbox?

Comment: @blex and Amy thanks for your input. 
Kevin Boucher I'd like to hear more of your solution, since coding, like art, has many interpretations. I already have my answer, thanks to Gerardo, but I'm curious what you would do too.

Comment: @Cyfer He said that because in your example, the checkboxes' values are identical to the label text (eg. `value="Item 3"`). If that's the text you want, you can just do `return $(this).val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector actually has the right tags. The problem is how you are trying to get the `label` text.

Your selector gives you the `<input>` that is checked
Using `.parent()` you can go one up to get the `<label>`
Then u use `.text()` to get the label text.
Finally use `.trim()` to remove the extra spaces at the ends of the text.

```
$(this).parent().text().trim();
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
function checkChecked(){
  var checktext = $('#13 input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().text().trim();
  }).get();
  console.log(checktext)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="control-label">Items</label>
<div class="controls">
  <div id="13" class="checkboxes columns-container columns-count-two">
    <div class="column-item">
      <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="13[]" value="Item 1" type="checkbox">Item 1
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="column-item">
      <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="13[]" value="Item 2" type="checkbox">Item 2
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="column-item">
      <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="13[]" value="Item 3" type="checkbox">Item 3
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick='checkChecked()'>Check checked</button>
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank you, something so simple, yet when I was going about it I struggled to wrap my head around it all. You were a great help, and gave the perfect answer! :)

Comment: Glad it helped. For this type of issues I recommend you paly around with the dev tools console, Code on!